# Amazon Product Advertising API, how do I know which product belongs to amazon and which belongs to amazon market place

Tags: e-commerce, amazon-product-api

I'm using Amazon Product Advertising API to list products on my site. I also want to show if the product belongs to Amazon or an Amazon Marketplace merchant.