# Amazon Product Advertising API, how to tell if product is supplied by Amazon

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm using the Amazon Product Advertising API to get products for my site. I need to be able to tell if the new items in the response are coming from Amazon or from a third party. It appears that until 11/01/2012 API this was possible through:

```xml
<ItemLookupResponse>
   <Items>
      <Item>
         <Offers>
             <Offer>
                <Merchant>
                   <MerchantId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MerchantId>
                   <Name>Amazon.com</Name>
```

However the **MerchantId** has now been removed from the Offers response group in the API.
**IsFulfilledByAmazon** is another one which has been removed.

The only thing I can find now which could determine if the item was provided by Amazon would be:

```xml
<Offer>
   <OfferListing>
      <IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>1</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
```

, as items with SuperSaverShipping are always supplied by Amazon - but I'm not sure if this is reliable?

Any one got a better idea how to do this?

There is an old article before the API change about how to do this, but is now outdated:[Amazon Product Advertising API, how do I know which product belongs to amazon and which belongs to amazon market place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954331/amazon-product-advertising-api-how-do-i-know-which-product-belongs-to-amazon-an)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can filter the results by setting the MerchantId in the request to "Amazon".
This will return only the offers which are offered by the Amazon merchant.

Notice that you can only set this variable to be "Amazon" or "All"...

Comment: Any chances to get only the prime shipping?

Comment: For the Prime shipping you have to iterate the results returned from Amazon  API, and filter only the prime ones.
You can do this by checking the Offer object and IsEligibleForPrime attribute